# Deploying another war file in tomcat within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, war

I have two Java EE dynamic web projects within Eclipse - a) Calculator project and b) CalculatorUser project. Both have HTTP endpoints. I can run both independently.

I want to use the war file created from the project Calculator & drop it into CalculatorUser. The aim is that both web applications run within the same tomcat instance (on localhost) and the CalculatorUser can send http messages to Calculator.

This is the important point: because of business reasons, CalculatorUser cannot just call the methods in Calculator, but needs to communicate with it webapp-to-webapp.

The whole thing is a sample for the users. I cannot drop Calculator.war in the tomcat/webapps folder because the users should be able to just get the CalculatorUser project & run the whole thing.

How do I deploy Calculator.war on tomcat server within eclipse in CalculatorUser project? Is there some configuration within Tomcat where I can specify the path of this war file?

Comment: So you want two webapps, but a single war? That's not possible. A war contains one webapp. Not two. A webapp may send HTTP requests to itself if you want to though, even if I don't see the point of doing that.

Comment: I think there would be two war files, wouldn't there? One that I specifically create using Eclipse export menu option in the Calculator project. And the second one that eclipse would create by iteslf for deployong to Tomcat.